# Получение доступа к Android/data/com... Android 11

Tags: java, android, android-intent, permissions, saf

Моё приложение предназначено исключительно для **Андроид 11**

Как видно на представленных скриншотах, некоторым файловым менеджерам удается получить доступ к этому каталогу

[image: Amaze file manager]

[image: Allowing a folder in DocumentsUI]

Я хочу сделать что-то подобное в Java.  Я пробовал много способов, но почти всегда меня отправляли либо на главную страницу DocumentsUI, либо в каталог /storage/emulated/0/.

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: На скриншоте подсказка где копать: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код для получения доступа к папкам после Android/data/ на Андроид 11 - 14

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
  intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUri("com.android.externalstorage.documents", "primary:Android/data/com.google.android.dialer"));
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Замените `com.google.android.dialer` на реальное имя пакета приложения

Для использования на 12-14 нужно сделать сброс DocumentsUI до заводских